# how to connect multiple input table to fact table in pentaho

Tags: pentaho-spoon

It would be helpful for me if somebody can tell me how to connect the multiple input tables in pentaho to one fact table?

[Pentaho table inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy0C1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like this, provided the Input tables have the same format, and the order does not matter:

[image]

Of course you can replace the `Table input` by a more complex treatment.

You can put a `Select value` between an Input and the Output to change the columns name, type and order. (Hint: right-click on the `Table input` to show its output field, and right-click on the `Table output` to show its input field, then move the two tables on the screen so the columns are side by side).

If the order does matter, drop the input flow replace the `Table output` with a `Sorted merge`.